ATMEL 2560 clears UDRIE bit after 2 received 2 chars
On MY ATMEL STUDIO 6.2 (running om XP sp. 4) my code (se below) suddenly stops after writing 2 chars (and only 2 chars).
After a intense debugging session in AS 6.2 it appears that the UCSR0A register (port Address: 0xc0) bit UDRE0  (0x20) is not set (0 -> 1) after transmitting 2 chars, which are fully and completely sent out.
I use the INITIALIZE - , IN- and OUT - routines described on page 206, page 207 and page 210.
It is written for an ATMEL 2560.
I have tried it on a P328 too.   Same results.
I have no idea what is wrong, please help .
Here is the Code:
        .CSEG
        .ORG    0x0000

INIT:   JMP     INITA
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET                   ; 000C     940C0080
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
L0032:  JMP     U0RXINT
L0034:  JMP     U0RXRDY
L0036:  JMP     U0TXINT
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET
        JMP     RESET

        .ORG    0X0080
U0RXINT:RETI

U0RXRDY:RETI

U0TXINT:RETI

        .ORG    0X0100
RESET:  JMP     INIT

INITA:  LDI     R16, HIGH (RAMEND)
        OUT     SPH, R16
        MOV     R21, R16
        LDI     R16, LOW (RAMEND)
        OUT     SPL, R16
        MOV     R22, R16
        STS     SPSAVH, R21
        STS     SPSAVL, R22
        CALL    SYSINIT

MLOOP:
        LDS     R21, SPSAVH
        LDS     R22, SPSAVL
        OUT     SPH, R21
        OUT     SPL, R22

MLP05:  LDS     R16, PROMP              ; udsend PROMP
MLP08:  CALL    DATUD
MLP10:  CALL    DATIN                   ; hent data til <R16>
        CPI     R16, 0X31               ; data = '1'
        BREQ    MLP15
        CPI     R16, 0X32               ; data = '2'
        BREQ    MLP20
        CPI     R16, 0X0D               ; data = CR
        BRNE    MLP10
        CALL    DOCRLF                  ; udsend CRLF
        RJMP    MLP05

MLP15:  SBI     PORTB, 5                ; sæt LED on
        RJMP    MLP08

MLP20:  CBI     PORTB, 5                ; sæt LED off
        RJMP    MLP08

SYSINIT:CLI
        LDI     R16, '>'                ; sÆT PROMP
        STS     PROMP, R16
        LDI     R16, 0XFF
        OUT     DDRB, R16               ; PORT B = OUT
        LDS     R16, PRR0
        ANDI    R16, 0XFE
        STS     PRR0, R16
        LDI     R17, 0X00
        LDI     R16, 0X67
        STS     BAUDH, R17
        STS     BAUDL, R16
        LDI     R18, 0X18
        LDI     R19, 0X06
        STS     UBRR0H, R17
        STS     UBRR0L, R16
        STS     UCSR0B, R18
        STS     UCSR0C, R19

;       LDI     R17, 0X00
;       LDI     R16, 0X68
;       STS     BAUDSH, R17
;       STS     BAUDSL, R16
;       LDI     R18, 0X18
;       LDI     R19, 0X06
;       STS     UBRR1H, R17
;       STS     UBRR1L, R16
;       STS     UCSR1B, R18
;       STS     UCSR1C, R19
        CALL    DOCRLF                  ; udsend CRLF
        RET

L00D1:  LDI     R16, 0X00
L00D2:  ST      X+, R16
        DEC     R17
        BRNE    L00D2
        RET

DATUD:  PUSH    R17
DATU05: LDS     R17, 0XC0
        SBRS    R17, 5
        BRNE    DATU05
        STS     UDR0, R16
        POP     R17
        RET

DATIN:  PUSH    R17
DATI05: LDS     R17, 0XC0
        SBRS    R17, 7
        BRNE    DATI05
        LDS     R16, UDR0
        POP     R17
        RET

DOCRLF: LDI     R16, 0X0D
        CALL    DATUD
        LDI     R16, 0X0A
        CALL    DATUD
        RET

        .DSEG
        .ORG    0x0200

INBUF:  .BYTE   80
SPSAVH: .BYTE   1
SPSAVL: .BYTE   1
BAUDH:  .BYTE   1
BAUDL:  .BYTE   1
BAUDSH: .BYTE   1
BAUDSL: .BYTE   1
BUFADRL:.BYTE   1
BUFADRH:.BYTE   1
PROMP:  .BYTE   1


You should ask in a programming stack, such as stackoverflow.

The two instuctions
BRNE    DATU05
BRNE    DATI05
cannot work properly, because the flags are not set by the instruction
LDS     R17, 0XC0
So the BRNE decision does not depend on the status register content, it depends on some other previous operation and creates wrong behaviour.
Replace the instructions by
RJMP    DATU05
RJMP    DATI05
because the required decision is already done by the previous instruction
SBRS    R17, xxx

Thanks a lot. I'll try that and test it.

Tried it. No change. It appears, that the OXCO register (UCSR0A) is not changed (any bit set) .  Not SET at all before doing TX.   Still TX'in 2 chars - no more ..... AND, btw. thanks for the hint - changing BRNE to RJMP.....
